# Apache Zeppelin - Cannot load dependency from custom maven repo

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have my library which I host in my custom maven repo. I want to use in the notebook. However when I try to load it it tries to load them from central repo instead of my custom repo

My zeppelin code:

```
%dep
z.reset();
z.addRepo("myTeam").url("http://maven.myHost.com/repository/myTeam").username("username").password("password");
z.load("myTeam:normalization-cache:jar-with-dependencies:1.1.14");
```

And this is the output

```
org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact myTeam:normalization-cache:jar-with-dependencies:1.1.14 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
```

So it always looks for the dependency in the central repo. How to change it so it could get it from my repo ?

Comment: can we use the dependency management feature of Zeppelin and give it a try. https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/usage/interpreter/dependency_management.html. I have found this to work reliably than the programmatic approach